# Grafting avocado

Tags: avocado, grafting

I have grafted avocado seedlings with hass scions. After 5 weeks, I unwrapped the grafting tape (I used kitchen foil for grafting tape). The scion par of graft is live and showing growth (not strong growth, though). However, the graft union turned brown. Can you please have a look at the images and advise if there is any way to take care of the union?[image]

[image]

[image]